# Implications of extending or getting a new visa for UK?

Tags: visas, uk

I and my son got a standard UK visa a couple of days back that ends in the first week of Jan 2020. It's our first UK visa.

Due to some unexpected personal circumstances we will not be able to travel until mid-March.

1) Any implications or any issue if we don't travel to UK?

2 If we want to travel in March, will there be any issues or problems getting a new Standard Visa or will it be rejected?

Comment: Not using a non immigrant visa doesn't hurt

Answer (score 3):

It's OK if you don't use your UK Standard Visitor Visa.

There is no such thing as extending the visa, though. If you are unable to travel before it expires, you can simply apply for a new visa.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Micheal really appreciate your quick reply